# Why kotlin coroutines are considered light weight?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

If coroutines is still using threads to run code in parallel why it is considered light weight?

In my understanding kotlin's `suspend` functions is transformed by compiler into state machine where each branch can be run on the same or different thread defined by developer. Coroutine builder, e,g, `launch{}`, responsible for that and `CoroutineContext` is what defines a thread to run on.

Parallelism achieved by sending block of code to the thread pool which leverage the same threads

There was a benchmark on 100k coroutines and 100k threads where coroutines pass without issue and threads throw exception (likely OutOfMemory). It brings me to idea I am missing something here.

Could you help me to understand what is missed here what makes coroutines run code block 100k in parallel without exceeding memory limits like threads do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pointing from the [article](https://medium.com/android-microsoft/kotlin-coroutines-1c8e009cb711)

> Every [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) has its own stack, typically 1MB. 64k is the least amount of stack space allowed per thread in the JVM while a simple coroutine in Kotlin occupies only a few dozen bytes of heap memory.

The Coroutine Dispatcher has a limit that only a certain amount of threads can be created.

Such as [Dispatchers.IO](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) has limit of 64 threads, [Dispatchers.Default](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) has limit of number of cores on your processor (2, 4, 6, 8, etc.) [Dispatchers.Unconfined](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html) cannot create new thread it runs on threads previously created by other dispatchers, here's proof: 500 operations having 10ms of sleep takes approx 5s (single-thread because it can't spawn a new) [try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/PrBEpa6SW).

Coroutines stick to a thread, and as soon as suspension point is reached, it leaves the Thread and frees it up letting it to pick up another coroutine if it is waiting. This way with less threads and less memory usage, that much concurrent work can be done.

The coroutines are managed to be suspended and resumed by a callback like object [`Continuation`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-continuation/) which is added as the last parameter to the function marked with `suspend` keyword at the time of compilation which lives in heap as other objects do and is responsible for the resume of coroutine, so Thousands of MBs space is not required in RAM to keep all the Threads alive. A typical 60-70 threads are created at max using `CommonPool` and are reused (if new coroutine is created it waits till another finishes).

Comment: Thank you for valuabe details.

Comment: not only Kotlin coroutines, but all other kinds of asynchronous activities (actors, CompletableFutures, etc) do not use own stacks and so have low memory consumption.

Comment: Thank you, I was curious what was special in couroutines that makes them more efficient rather than threads when they still leverage them. Major points here were limit on amout of threads, reusing each thread and self maanging suspension\resume instead of delegating it to OS (as Marco points out) which is more efficient rather then in case of traditional Threads

Comment: I would add memory (especially stack) usage as one of the foremost points.

Answer (score 8):

The main saving comes from the fact that a single thread can run any number of coroutines, by way of cooperative multitasking. When you launch 100,000 coroutines, they run on as many threads as there are CPU cores, but when you start 100,000 threads, the JVM creates that many native threads. Note that the level of parallelism is equal in both cases, and limited to the number of CPU cores.

The only thing that changes is scheduling: in the classical case, the OS suspends and resumes threads, assigning them to CPU cores. With coroutines, the coroutines suspend themselves (this is their cooperative aspect) and the `Dispatcher` resumes them later on, running other coroutines in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

**Lightweight:** You can run many coroutines on a single thread due to support for suspension, which doesn't block the thread where the coroutine is running. Suspending saves memory over blocking while supporting many concurrent operations.

**Fewer memory leaks:** Use [structured concurrency](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#structured-concurrency) to run operations within a scope.